# Google Maps API - InfoWindow with Place Details auto-opens without content

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new here and I'm a complete newbie with Google Maps API or anything API for that matter! I've managed to cobble something together however so bear with me

I've got my base map loading, a marker dropping on top of the business *(place)* I'm working on and I have the *infowindow* populating with the relevant business details pulled from the Places API. When I click the marker, the *infowindow* appears and the content displays. So far, so good

Now I want the *infowindow* to display automatically when the map loads. I have this working but the *infowindow* that appears is empty... just a small bubble with an X to close appears. If I then click the marker, the *infowindow* with the business details appears

My code has been mushed together from snippets I found here and there so I know it's a mess and that something in there is not triggering my desired *infowindow*. Can anyone spot where I've gone wrong?

Thanks in advance,

C

---

For reference, when I click the marker, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxend.png) *(I've blanked the details)*

However, when I run it to auto-open, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McEQT.png)

---

```
    <script>      
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 54.71891, lng: -8.716691},
      zoom: 16,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      keyboardShortcuts: false,
      disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
      draggable: false
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.getDetails({
      placeId: 'ChIJBy4MUDc8X0gR7LGOUiAYQeQ'
    }, function(place, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
          infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
            '<p>' + place.formatted_address + '</p>' +
            '<p><a href="https://www.google.com/maps?cid=16447453841236865516"><strong>Get Directions / Larger Map</strong> </a></p>' +
            '</div>');
        });
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you set the content of the `infowindow` by clicking the marker. So if you set the content before the `addListener` I think it would be OK. Like this:

```
<script>      
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 54.71891, lng: -8.716691},
        zoom: 16,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        keyboardShortcuts: false,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        draggable: false
    });

    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.getDetails({
        placeId: 'ChIJBy4MUDc8X0gR7LGOUiAYQeQ'
    }, function(place, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: place.geometry.location
            });
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
                '<p>' + place.formatted_address + '</p>' +
                '<p><a href="https://www.google.com/maps?cid=16447453841236865516"><strong>Get Directions / Larger Map</strong> </a></p>' +
                '</div>');
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

I hope that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks MKiss! That done it and the map centre corrects when the infowindow appears